# Redirect to named url pattern directly from urls.py in django?

Tags: django, redirect

In Django, how can I do a simple redirect directly from urls.py? Naturally I am a well organized guy, favoring the DRY principle, so I would like to get the target based on it's named url pattern, rather than hard coding the url.

Answer (score 222, accepted):

You can use [`RedirectView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview).

If you are on Django 1.4 or 1.5, you can do this:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^some-page/$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('my_named_pattern'), permanent=False)),
    ...
```

If you are on Django 1.6 or above, you can do this:

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^some-page/$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='my_named_pattern', permanent=False)),
    ...
```

In Django 1.9, the default value of `permanent` has changed from True to False. Because of this, if you don't specify the `permanent` keyword argument, you may see this warning:

> RemovedInDjango19Warning: Default value of 'RedirectView.permanent' will change from True to False in Django 1.9. Set an explicit value to silence this warning.

Comment: Just a note, remember that the RedirectView has permanent=True as default.

Comment: You can redirect everything! Like so: ```(r'^.*/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='http://newurl.com')),```

Comment: RedirectView will have permanent=False as default in Django 1.9.

Comment: Can someone explain what is 'my_named_pattern' in above example.

Comment: passing `pattern_name` argument to `RedirectView` executes reverse for you at call time using given pattern name. Other [useful parameters include `permanent` and `query_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.RedirectView.url).

Comment: If you don't pass `query_string=True`, then the redirect will lose the query string, eg: `?gclid=foobar`.

Comment: In Django 2.1 and later, use `re_path()` not `url()`; see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#url

Answer (score 41):

This works for me.

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^some-page/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/')),
    ...
```

In above example `'/'` means it will redirect to index page,
where you can add any url patterns also.

Comment: Just a note, remember that the `RedirectView` has `permanent=True` as default in older versions of Django, and `permanent=False` as default in Django versions >= 1.9.

Answer (score 34):

for django v2+

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    # this example uses named URL 'hola-home' from app named hola
    # for more redirect's usage options: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/
    path('', lambda request: redirect('hola/', permanent=False)),
    path('hola/', include("hola.urls")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: @Ali

Permanent redirects usually have HTTP code 301, temporary redirects usually have code 302.

Permanent redirects are used to inform the browser of site's structural changes.

Temporary redirects are used to indicate a new page to be shown after a dynamic server side action like login.

According to the documentation `permanent=False` is the default.

For more details please read:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections#Permanent_redirections

Answer (score 11):

I was trying to redirect all 404s to the home page and the following worked great:

```py
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
# under urlpatterns, added:
url(r'^.*/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/home/')),
url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/home/')),
```

Answer (score 9):

This way is supported in older versions of django if you cannot support RedirectView

In view.py

```
def url_redirect(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/new_url/")
```

In the url.py

```
url(r'^old_url/$', "website.views.url_redirect", name="url-redirect"),
```

You can make it permanent by using `HttpResponsePermanentRedirect`

Answer (score 2):

You could do straight on the urls.py just doing something like:

```
url(r'^story/(?P<pk>\d+)/',
        lambda request, pk: HttpResponsePermanentRedirect('/new_story/{pk}'.format(pk=pk)))
```

Just ensure that you have the new URL ready to receive the redirect!!
Also, pay attention to the kind of redirect, in the example I'm using **Permanent Redirect**

Answer (score 0):

If you need to capture part of the url including slashes and directly reuse that in the redirect, you can use `re_path` like this:

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import re_path

re_path(r"admin/old_module/(.+)$", lambda req, rest: redirect(f"/admin/new_module/{rest}"))
```

Here `rest` is a positional argument containing the first capture group `(.+)`. More arguments/capture groups could be added in the same manner. (see [`re_path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#re-path))