# error in URLconf in django - improperly configured

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to redirect to my app URL from project url for homepage which is `r'^$'`.
I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706489/redirect-to-named-url-pattern-directly-from-urls-py-in-django). but it did not help.
This is the `urls.py` of my project:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', redirect('home')),
    url(r'^link/', include('link_app.urls')),
    )
```

This is the `urls.py` of my app link:

```
urlpatterns=patterns('',
url(r'^$', LinkListView.as_view(), name='home'),
)
```

so basically I am aiming at 
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/` and `http://127.0.0.1:8000/link/` to be processed by the same view.

I get the following error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /
The included urlconf link_project.urls doesn't have any patterns in it
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.6
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    
The included urlconf link_project.urls doesn't have any patterns in it
```

Comment: Again with the code highlighting of random words. Please stop that.

Comment: What is you directory structure? Your question refers to `link_app` but the traceback says the problem is with `link_project`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've chosen the wrong answer on the [page you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706489/redirect-to-named-url-pattern-directly-from-urls-py-in-django). You can't use the `redirect` shortcut in your URL patterns, since it is not a view. Using `RedirectView` is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

Change your projects urls.py file to modify the

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^/$',RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('home'))),
url(r'^link/$', LinkedListView.as_view(), name='home'),
```

The solution assumes that your link app has only one url, 
for multiple urls in your app try adding a name attribute to url(r'^link/$')

Answer (score 0):

If the view which you want to process your urls is the one inside `link_app`, then do the following:

**urls.py** of your project:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('link_app.urls')),
    )
```

**urls.py** of your `link_app`:

```
urlpatterns=patterns('',
url(r'/$', LinkListView.as_view(), name='home'),
url(r'link/$', LinkListView.as_view(), name='home_link'),
)
```

Let me know if this worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Just include your `link_app.urls` immediately after the admin urls with regex `r'^'`.

Then use the following patterns within `link_app.urls` to call the same view:

```
urlpatterns=patterns('',
    url(r'^$', LinkListView.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^link/$', LinkListView.as_view(), name='link'),
)
```

Comment: having `r'^'` will redirect even /accounts/ or /register/ to `link_app.urls`, which is not correct right?

Comment: Yes, but you ordering matters, so you can first add url patterns for this urls and put `r'^'` to last position.