# How can I serve a static page from urls.py?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-staticfiles

I have a Django site where I need to serve the `favicon.ico` - which, being a static file, is at `STATIC_URL/path/to/favicon.ico`. Is it possible to do so straight from the `urls.py`? (i.e. without creating a specific *view* only for that)

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15706489/520779) that shows how to map from a pattern to another [named] one, but that's not what I need: I want to map from a pattern to a static URL. Something like:

```python
url(r'^favicon.ico$', view_that_serves_from_STATIC_ROOT_or_redirects_to_STATIC_URL),
```

Is it possible? And if not, what would be the least laborious way?

P.S. I'm using Django 1.4.14 with Python 2.6.0 (and no, due to constraints in my environment I can't upgrade to a newer version...)

Comment: Are you using Apache, nginx or something else? You should try to handle this within that rather than Django.

Comment: @schillingt Yes, I can do that! Thanks for your suggestion. Right now I'm just using `runserver` to show a prototype to my customers, but I can postpone it to production if I have to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do should be done outside of django. All assets such as CSS, JS, images can reliably be served through something like nginx. I would also recommend that you take a look at django-storage that can help with that. You can read more about how to handle static files in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)

*That said*, you can serve plain templates through `urls.py` using django's [`TemplateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#subclassing-generic-views). This can be useful if you don't need to make any changes within the template itself. (Works in django 1.4)

Comment: I think you're right! I've always used simple `/static/...` to keep things simple, but I know that's not the right way to do it. In this case, however, I'm not linking to a static file within a template, but serving a file with a predefined name (`favicon.ico`; I guess `robots.txt` also falls within that category). I'll check your other sugestion shortly (even if, in production, I leave this to Apache).

Comment: Using `TemplateView` didn't work - since my file is a binary one, not a template - but while browsing the link you provided I found `RedirectView`, which solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: TemplateView link is now broken