# Redirect url from django application

Tags: django, url-rewriting, django-urls

I have a basic application built in Django, which only works if I enter:

`http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/polls`. How can I rewrite this in my **urls.py** file so that `http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/polls` will redirect me to `http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/` ?

My **urls.py** file for the main project:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

My **urls.py** file from the application:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

My project structure:

```
├── blog  
│   ├── __init__.py  
│   ├── __init__.pyc  
│   ├── settings.py  
│   ├── settings.pyc  
│   ├── urls.py  
│   ├── urls.pyc  
│   ├── wsgi.py  
│   └── wsgi.pyc  
├── db.sqlite3  
├── manage.py  
├── polls  
│   ├── admin.py  
│   ├── admin.pyc  
│   ├── __init__.py  
│   ├── __init__.pyc  
│   ├── migrations  
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py  
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc  
│   │   ├── __init__.py  
│   │   └── __init__.pyc  
│   ├── models.py  
│   ├── models.pyc  
│   ├── templates  
│   │   └── polls  
│   │       ├── detail.html  
│   │       ├── index.html  
│   │       ├── results.html  
│   │       └── static  
│   │           └── polls  
│   │               ├── css  
│   │               │   ├── semantic.css  
│   │               │   ├── semantic.min.css  
│   │               │   ├── sidebar.css  
│   │               │   ├── sidebar.min.css  
│   │               │   ├── sidebar.min.js  
│   │               │   └── style.css  
│   │               ├── images  
│   │               └── js  
│   │                   ├── jquery-1.11.2.min.js  
│   │                   ├── semantic.js  
│   │                   ├── semantic.min.js  
│   │                   ├── sidebar.js  
│   │                   └── sidebar.min.js  
│   ├── tests.py  
│   ├── tests.pyc  
│   ├── urls.py  
│   ├── urls.pyc  
│   ├── views.py  
│   └── views.pyc  
├── readme.txt  
├── requirements.txt  
├── templates  
│   └── admin  
│       └── base_site.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also include your whole polls app on '/' by doing:

```
    url(r'^', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
```

Also, see here for more information on redirecting in urls.py:
[Redirect to named url pattern directly from urls.py in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706489/redirect-to-named-url-pattern-directly-from-urls-py-in-django)

In your case it would be something like:

```
    from django.views.generic import RedirectView

    url(r'^polls/', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='polls:index')
```

Comment: `url(r'^', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),` this was what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

As far as I undesrstand you don't ant to redirect from `/polls/` to `/` but want to show the polls index at the home page.  If so then just move the `index` url from the `polls/urls.py` into the main `urls.py`:

```
from polls.views import IndexView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

**UPDATE**: It is a bad practice to use hard-coded urls in the django templates/code.  You should always use the [`{% url %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#url) template tag and the [`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) function.  This will allow you to change urls as you want without breaking the code.

So link to the index page should be like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home page</a>
```

And, for example, link to the poll details:

```
<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' poll.pk %}">Poll #{{ poll.pk }}</a>
```

In the model's [`get_absolute_url()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) method use the [`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse).

Comment: Ok, it works @catavaran but the problem is that the other links won't work (they will redirect me to an error page) . That's why I wanted a redirect.

Comment: how should I modify the other links so that your method will work for other pages. Your solution is ok for the first page, but if I try to click a link from that page, it will give me error for the other pages

Comment: You have no page to redirect.  The `/` url doesn't have any associated view. This is why I suggest to map this url to your `IndexView`.  As for broken links.. see the update in my answer. Always use django's url resolver for the links.