# URL routing in the Django framework

Tags: django, http, redirect, web

So I'm building a fairly simple website that allows users to create and edit profiles. I'm in the process of creating the URLs for the site, which follow the following "rules":

- `www.website.com` should redirect to home.
- `www.website.com/profile/person` should redirect to `person`'s profile.
- `www.website.com/profile/person/extra/useless/info` should redirect to `person`'s profile, as the URL should be "trimmed" after `profile/person/`.
- `www.website.com/profile` should redirect back to `www.website.com` which will redirect to home.

My code so far is as follows.

```
# my_site/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', include('my_app.urls')),
    url(r'^profile/', include('my_app.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Part 2:

```
# my_app/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url
from django.http import HttpResponse

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^(?P<username>[\w-]*)/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
   url(r'^(?P<username>[^\w-])/$', views.profile, name='profile'), # still link to the profile
   url(r'^$', views.home, name="home"),
]
```

With this code, when the user enters `www.mysite.com/profile`, the user *is* redirected to the home page, but the address bar still reads `www.mysite.com/profile`, which I do not want. I want it to read `www.mysite.com`. Also, the 3rd rule in the rule list I gave above is not obeyed. I was thinking of having a URL "cleaning" function, which trims unwanted parts of the URL, but I have no idea how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is "home page" the same as profile page? I am asking this because you pointed all your apps url to views.profile. Can you also post your views.py?

Comment: I'm mistaken. I meant to point to `views.home`. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

To get the path in the browser to change you need to use an actual http redirect, not just a fallback in Django url matching.

```
# my_site/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', include('my_app.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]


# my_app/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import RedirectView    

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^profile/(?P<username>[^/]+)/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
   url(r'^profile/(?P<username>[^/]+)/(.*)?', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='profile')),
   url(r'^profile/$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='home')),
   url(r'^$', views.profile, name="home"),
]
```

to explain:

- `^profile/(?P<username>[^/]+)/$` matches `mysite.com/profile/my-user-name/` with no junk at the end
- `'^profile/(?P<username>[^/]+)/(.*)?'` matches the case with junk at the end (after a valid username and `/`) ...you want to require the slash before looking for junk portion otherwise if you have two users `john` and `johnsmith` you would always match `johnsmith` in url as the `john` user (treating the `smith` as extra junk). We then do a real http redirect to the canonical profile url
- `'^profile/$'` matches just `mysite.com/profile/` and does a real http redirect to home page

for more about redirecting see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15706497/202168

also of course the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect