# Redirect django blog. I want that the url http://example.com redirects automatically to http://example.com/blog/

Tags: python, django

I have a blog made in django in a VPS. The blog is working fine but to access it I have to write the url example.com/blog/

What I'm trying is to make an automatic redirection so when a user enters example.com/ it automatically redirects to example.com/blog/

The project is set under apache.

This is my the configuration in myproject/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace="blog")),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

This is the configuration of myproject/blog/urls.py that right now is formed by a post list and a post detail:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Index
url(r'^(?P<page>\d+)?/?$', ListView.as_view(
    model=Post,
    paginate_by=5,
    ),
    name='index'
    ),
# Individual posts
url(r'^(?P<pub_date__year>\d{4})/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$', DetailView.as_view(
    model=Post,
    ),
    name='post'
    ),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I already tried to add a .htaccess with different configurations but it's not working.

Is there a way to redirect from django?

Comment: write one view for example.com/ and redirect to /blog

Comment: Why have you set it under /blog in the first place? Why not host it at / ?

Comment: @GeoJacob thanks for your reply. I'm not sure how I can do this, could you please set a code example

Comment: @DanielRoseman that is a good question. The answer is because I would prefer the url to appear as example.com/blog/. However if I still have problems about this I might change it to the root.

Comment: [Redirect to named url int urls.py](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706489/redirect-to-named-url-pattern-directly-from-urls-py-in-django)

Comment: You don't say how you're hosting your site, but seems likely this would be best done directly in the Apache conf.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I host the site with apache. I tried to redirect with .htaccess but it's not working. If I don't find the solution I'll do what you suggested of changing everything to root

Comment: .htaccess needs to be specifically enabled. You should do it directly in the virtualhost configuration: see for example [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache-and-nginx).

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that you want that / to redirect to /blog/ for that you can create a temporary index view and redirect the response to /blog/

```
url(r'^', temp_index, name='index'),

def temp_index(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog/')
```

If you want that `/` must show `/blog` then replace

`url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace="blog")),` with
`url(r'^', include('blog.urls', namespace="blog")),`

Comment: It's not working. It says that the page isn't redirecting properly. It looks that there is a conflict between the root page and the /blog/ page. The redirection works however. When I put / it goes to /blog/