# Django redirect based on parts of url pattern

Tags: python, django, redirect

So I have this small simple problem that I can't really find a solution to.

I would like to redirect all links on the form `r'^blogg/` to `r'^blog/'`. I would think there is a solution similar to the accepted answer in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706489/redirect-to-named-url-pattern-directly-from-urls-py-in-django), but it doesn't work that well. Note that the blog-application has many sub-url-patterns, so a solution like `RedirectView.as_view(url="/blog/")` would not work.

In my main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^blogg/', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name="blog")),
url(r'^blog/', include("blog.urls", namespace="blog")),
```

The solution above returns HTTP 410 (Gone) for all sub-urls of `blogg`. I suspect this is due to the missing `url` argument in `RedirectView.as_view()`.

Thanks in advance for all answers!

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do this entirely in urls.py. But a simple view function could work:

```
url(r'^blogg/(?P<rest>.+)$', views.redirect_prefix),


from django.shortcuts import redirect

def redirect_prefix(request, rest):
    return redirect('/blog/{}'.format(rest))
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^blogg/',include("blog.urls", namespace="ignoreme") ),
url(r'^blog/', include("blog.urls", namespace="blog")),
```

it both should strip the first part (blog/ or blogg/) from url and then manage the rest equally. And if you will use `{% url "blog:this_view" %}` then on next page your customer will be on the blog/ part anyway

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yes, I have considered this solution, but it's not ideal in my opinion (Because of some social plugins). Although, this is my fallback solution :)