# Django: redirect in URLconf with namespaced app

Tags: python, django, redirect

I want to achieve the same as this question : [Redirect to named url pattern directly from urls.py in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706489/redirect-to-named-url-pattern-directly-from-urls-py-in-django)

but with a twist: my application has a namespace, and the selected answer no longer works right.

It works only if I include the namespace (`app:`) in the `pattern_name` parameter of `RedirectView` :

**project/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^', include('app.urls', namespace='app', app_name='app')
)
```

**app/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^newurl/$', my_view, name="my_view"),
    url(r'^oldurl/$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='app:my_view')
)
```

But of course this is ugly and prevents the app from being reusable, which undermines the point of namespacing... So surely, there is a way to do this right, right?