# Multiple urls pointing do /static/ dir django

Tags: django

I have two apps under different URLs. But the static file dir is the same. So I'd need to tell to django that when `/myapp/static/jpg.jpg` is asked it would redirect it to `/static/jpg.jpg` and would do the same for `myotherapp/static/jpg.jpg`. This is simple todo in apache conf - just map `/myapp/static/` to `/static/`.
But can it be done in django?

Better example.
I have `www.myapp.com` and `www.myotherapp.com`. They are on my server as `localhost/myapp` and `localhost/myotherapp/` and static files are on `localhost/static`. So I can't access the `static` uri with URL

Comment: When you write about `/myapp/static/jpg.jpg` or `/static/jpg.jpg` do you mean local directory paths on the server or URLs used in a browser?

Comment: Why aren't you using the `static` tag?

Comment: Add your apps static path in `STATICFILES_DIRS` variables in your `settings.py`.

Comment: @LudwikTrammer server URLs

Comment: @MihkelL. have a look into here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706489/redirect-to-named-url-pattern-directly-from-urls-py-in-django

Comment: @Mortezaipo THis doesn't work in my case. The redirect doesn't go to the other app. even with `urlpatterns = [ url(r'^myapp/static/(?P<resource>.*)', RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/%(resource)s')), ..]`

Comment: @MihkelL. You can try it: separate your 'static' directory to some place else (like third app which just only has 'static' url). and then call it with url like: `http://file.myapp.com/static/`.