# Django redirectView returns None

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to use redirect view in django, but I keep getting this error:

> The view gp_accountant.gp_taxes.views.TaxRateDeleteView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

I've based my code on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706489/redirect-to-named-url-pattern-directly-from-urls-py-in-django).

Anyone knows where the problem lies?

This is my url file (path: `get-paid/gp_accountant/gp_taxes/urls.py`):

```
app_name = 'gp_taxes'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TaxesListView.as_view(), name='list'),
    url(
        r'^delete_rate/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        TaxRateDeleteView.as_view(pattern_name='accountant:gp_taxes:update'),
        name='delete_rate'
    ),
]
```

The TaxRateDeleteView:

```
class TaxRateDeleteView(RedirectView):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        TaxRate.objects.get(id=int(kwargs['pk'])).delete()
```

Comment: **Using a redirect view for deleting objects is a bad idea**. You should not be deleting objects with get requests like this. The [`DeleteView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#deleteview) would be a better place to start.

Comment: Thanks for notice. I've upvoted answer mentioning this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@FazilZaid almost correct, you need to return last line of his answer. Problem is that your `dispatch` doesn't return anything in general it should return `HttpResponseRedirect` so to make it work with `super` call you need to provide `success_url` to your view

```
class TaxRateDeleteView(RedirectView):
    success_url = # <- your url here

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        TaxRate.objects.get(id=int(kwargs['pk'])).delete()
        return super(TaxRateDeleteView,self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Also as per this comment by @Alasdair

> Using a redirect view for deleting objects is a bad idea. You should not be deleting objects with get requests like this.

You should use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView which is right way to delete object, instead of RedirectView

Comment: Worked like a charm. +1 for mentioning a better way for performing delete.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your view,

```
class TaxRateDeleteView(RedirectView):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        TaxRate.objects.get(id=int(kwargs['pk'])).delete()
        return super(TaxRateDeleteView,self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Call super on dispatch method of your view.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be overriding the dispatch method.

Try something like this instead:

```
class TaxRateDeleteView(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        TaxRate.objects.get(id=int(kwargs['pk'])).delete()   
        return reverse('delete_rate')
```

Comment: I don't think putting logic into `get_redirect_url` is right approach. Overall I expect it only to give me url not delete anything.

Comment: Why is it any better in the dispatch method? That way it only happens if everything else is correct for the redirect view.

Comment: Ok, to be fair there is a delete method on the RedirectView, which would be the best place to put it, though you would need to make sure that it is a delete request being sent to the view.  I don't think dispatch is the best place for deleting objects either.