# How to redirect to an explicitly named url in Django?

Tags: python, django, redirect

I am trying to have a redirect to a specific page base on a variable in my views.py:

```
redirect(f'feed/user/{first_user}')
```

But by having it like this it redirects me to the url:

```
feed/search/feed/user/first_user
```

instead I would like to redirect to the url

```
feed/user/first_user
```

I know that the `feed/search/` part is appended because the `search` url in my urls.py calls the function that should redirect but I would like to keep it that way and only change the redirect.

URLS.PY:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', login_required(PostListView.as_view()), name='feed-home'),
    path('user/<str:username>/', login_required(UserPostListView.as_view()), name='user-feed'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', login_required(views.post_detail), name='post-detail'),
    path('comment_delete/', login_required(views.comment_delete), name='comment-delete'),
    path('post/new/', login_required(PostCreateView.as_view()), name='post-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update', login_required(PostUpdateView.as_view()), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete', login_required(PostDeleteView.as_view()), name='post-delete'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='feed-about'),
    path('like/', login_required(views.post_like), name="post-likes"),
    path('comment_create/', login_required(views.comment_create), name="comment-create"),
    path('search/', login_required(views.user_search), name="user-search"),
]
```

Comment: Can you use `reverse` to generate the URL? Can you share the urls.py where the path you are redirecting to is defined?

Comment: @KuldeepSinghSidhu this gives me EOL syntax error^^ and yes I share urls.py

Comment: I think there was a synatx error: TRY THIS `(f'feed/user/{first_user.split("/")[-1]}')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
[Redirect to named url pattern directly from urls.py in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706489/redirect-to-named-url-pattern-directly-from-urls-py-in-django)
Or this:
https://adriennedomingus.com/blog/working-with-urls-in-python-amp-django

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you. I have added the following: `return redirect(reverse('user-feed', kwargs={'username' : first_user}))`

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a view name and it's arguments to `redirect`. Looks like you want the `user-feed` view?

```
redirect('user-feed', username=first_user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to redirect

```
return redirect('/accounts/twitter')
```

`'/accounts/twitter'` is your url where you want to move. we create these urls in urls.py file

you can also use below code to move on particular site

```
def my_view(request):
    ...
    return redirect('https://example.com/')
```